# Ncrack: Error string: "bad string length 361355397buffer_get_string: buffer error"

Tags: brute-force

when i attempt to use Ncrack with the syntax:

`ncrack -p 22 -user MyUserName -P passwords.txt MyIPAdress`

I am hit with the error:

`bad string length 361355397buffer_get_string: buffer error`

And google shows no results for this error string so im a little stuck.

Does anyone know what this error message means and how I would go about rectifying it? For context: I was attempting a Dictionary Bruteforce attack on port 22 (SSH protocol) using a password list to test the security of one of my devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question for Ncrack support.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and it has been fixed on the latest Ncrack version, which is available on svn:

https://nmap.org/ncrack/#svn

- I am the author of Ncrack

Comment: Might be worth mentioning you're a developer on this, maybe give a little more information, and of course, update once its fixed.

Comment: It is obvious I am a developer on this, since I mentioned that I am currently working on it. I will of course update my answer once it is fixed.